# Adding non-clustered index for multiple columns in asp.net mvc configuration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

Let's say I have a table - `UserToChannel_tbl` which has following fields - `Id, UserId and ChannelId`. I am deriving `EntityTypeConfiguration` and putting all properties in that as below (example) -

```
public class UserToChannelConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserToChannel>
{
    public UserToChannelConfiguration(){

        HasKey(p => p.Id);

        Property(p => p.Id)
        .HasColumnName("Id")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption((DatabaseGeneratedOption?) DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.UserId)
        .HasColumnName("UserId").IsRequired();
        HasRequired(p => p.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.UserId);

        Property(p => p.ChannelId)
        .HasColumnName("ChannelId").IsRequired();
        HasRequired(p => p.Channel).WithMany().HasForeignKey(t => t.ChannelId);
    }
}
```

Now, the table already has clustered index on `Id` column, but I also need a non-clustered index on `UserId, ChannelId` column. Is there a way to achieve this here instead of doing this in `Migration` class or  anywhere else. Seems much simpler to me if I can define all my properties at one place. I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF6.

Comment: In EF 6.1, Yes you can define indexes through attribute or Fluent API. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#PropertyIndex

Answer (score 0):

EF still cant do indexes so migrating SQL such as 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_User_u_username] ON [dbo].[BlockedUsers] ([User_u_username])
is not going to happen.
The migration tool for code first is fine for the general cases, not the edge cases it seems.